# Find the matrix A in the following

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
2 & -6&-4 \\
-2 & 7& 3 \\
3&-8&-6
\end{array} \right]^{-1} +2 \cdot A= \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
7 & 2&5 \\
6 & -10& -7 \\
5&-8&-5
\end{array} \right]$$

I can seem to solve this question. I move the inverse matrix to the right of the equation and add both those matrices. Finally I multiply 1/2 to the final matrix for A but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: that should work.  How do you know that it doesn't?

Comment: it's a question generator and it outputs similar types of questions but I keep getting them wrong...

Comment: Am I allowed to add an inverse matrix to an ordinary matrix?

Comment: I find it strange to refer to being allowed to do something or not; it's not like the matrix police will come after you if do it or not.  However, yes, you can add the inverse of a matrix to another matrix of the same dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You have something like $B^{-1}+2A=C\Rightarrow A=1/2(C-B^{-1})$. Now the only problem is to compute $B^{-1}=1/2 \left(\begin{array}{ccc}18& -4 & 10\\
-3 & 0 & 2\\
-5 & -2 & 2\end{array}\right)$
You should look up inverting a matrix.

Comment: Why did you factor out a 1/2?

Comment: Well the first is because $2A=C-B^{-1}\Rightarrow A=1/2(C-B^{-1})$ and the second one because I thought is was easier to wrote the matrix $B^{-1}$ like that.